# In Wix, why can I not get XmlConfig, uninstall, delete to work?

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.6

I need to remove elements from an existing config file on uninstall. Here is the relevant Wix:

```
<Component Id="Dynamics.exe.config" DiskId="1" Permanent="yes">
    <File Id="AppConfig" Name="Dynamics.exe.config" Source="$(var.ProgramFilesDir)\Microsoft Dynamics\GP2010\Dynamics.exe.config" KeyPath="yes" />
    <util:XmlConfig
                          Id="AppSettings"
                          Action="create"
                          ElementPath="//configuration"
                          Name="appSettings"
                          File="[#AppConfig]"
                          Sequence="1"
                          VerifyPath="appSettings"
                          Node="element"
                          On="install"/>

    <util:XmlConfig
                          Id="AppSettings1"
                          Action="create"
                          ElementPath="//configuration/appSettings"
                          Name="add"
                          File="[#AppConfig]"
                          Sequence="2"
                          VerifyPath="add[\[]@key='AppName'[\]]"
                          Node="element"
                          On="install"/>
    <util:XmlConfig
                          Id="AppSettingsKey1"
                          ElementPath="AppSettings1"
                          Name="key"
                          Value="AppName"
                          File="[#AppConfig]"
                          Sequence="3" />
    <util:XmlConfig
                          Id="AppSettingsValue1"
                          ElementPath="AppSettings1"
                          Name="value"
                          Value="MyApp"
                          File="[#AppConfig]"
                          Sequence="4" />
    <util:XmlConfig
                          Id="AppSettingsRemove1"
                          Action="delete"
                          ElementPath="//configuration/appSettings"
                          File="[#AppConfig]"
                          Sequence="2"
                          VerifyPath="add[\[]@key='AppName'[\]]"
                          Node="element"
                          On="uninstall"/>
```

The create Actions run. However, the delete/uninstall Action does not run. It does not modify the file. It seems like the file is being skipped over during an uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

You have configure the component **Permanent** attribute as Yes. That way the change will be kept during uninstall.

Try set as false.

---

I have test the following code, and it meets your requirements.
You can find full test code [here](https://github.com/crazy0man/WiXLab/tree/master/Example/WixUtilXMLConfig/WixUtilXMLConfig.UninstallChangeTest)

```
<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents"
                Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="CMP_ConfigFile"
             Guid="{24D22D04-1A98-40D1-83EC-87E68A87A07C}"
             Permanent="yes"
             KeyPath="yes"
             NeverOverwrite="yes">
    <File Id="ConfigFile"
          src="administration.config"></File>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="CMP_XMLConfigInstallChange"
             Guid="{B1B3B46A-0606-44F4-AEB6-58C5019F5C82}"
             KeyPath="yes">
    <util:XmlConfig Id="Add_ElementTest"
                    File="[#ConfigFile]"
                    ElementPath="/configuration/configSections"
                    Action="create"
                    Name="section"
                    Node="element"
                    On="install"
                    Sequence="5000">
      <util:XmlConfig Id="Name_Test"
                      File="[#ConfigFile]"
                      ElementId="Add_ElementTest"
                      Name="name"
                      Value="TEST"></util:XmlConfig>
    </util:XmlConfig>

  </Component>

  <Component Id="CMP_XMLConfig_UninstallChange"
             Guid="{E1A01B17-247E-4717-8DC0-A923A8E90BE4}"
             KeyPath="yes">
    <util:XmlConfig Id="Remove_ElementTest"
                    File="[#ConfigFile]"
                    ElementPath="/configuration/configSections"
                    VerifyPath="/configuration/configSections/section[\[]@name='TEST'[\]]"
                    Action="delete"
                    Node="element"
                    On="uninstall"
                    Sequence="5000">
    </util:XmlConfig>

  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Comment: Are saying I should change where I have Permanent="yes" to Permanent="false"? Wouldn't that remove the file during an uninstall?

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstand your question. Do you want to rollback your installation change during uninstall or you just want to do some change during uninstall which is not done by installation?

Comment: During an uninstall, I want to rollback changes using the elements with the Action of "delete". I cannot get those actions to fire. I do not want the file to be deleted. To summarize, on install AppSetting elements are created, then on uninstall those elements need to be removed. However, the file must remain on the disk.

Comment: For anyone confused because "Please try the above code" is *not* a good explanation, the trick here is to **make the xml transforms a *separate, permanent="no" component***. Hopefully this will help future visitors.