# modify attribute value of a node in xml file using windows wix file

Tags: xml, wix

I am trying to modify the value of an attribute in xml file.
I have a child node in my xml file, which contains attributes and corresponding values. I would like to update the value using wix project.
looking for a help on how can I modify the value or replace xml node?

Comment: I got a clue that we can use util:XmlConfig, and it is under UtilExtension. But when I add it, it shows error as Product as invalid child element util;XmlConfig. so where we can use it?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a reference to WixUtilExtension.dll to your project. And in Wix element should namespace declaration:

```
<Wix  xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
```

Comment: Yes, adding namespace works. to add this XmlConfig, I have added a component under directory, and created a patch(.msp). Once I applied the patch, I am unable to uninstall the patch from updates. I tried by adding KeyPath="Yes" for the component. Also tried by adding XmlConfig block to the existing component itself. What can we do to make this patch(.msp) uninstallable. Is there any attribute we need to add for that?

Comment: Look here:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573058/in-wix-why-can-i-not-get-xmlconfig-uninstall-delete-to-work). Seems it can be your case.

Comment: As I am trying to update an xml file, xml file which is created at the time of installation. Here I am just taking the xml file from my source directory and copying to the installation path. So I am adding the xmlconfig code block to the same existing component. because once xml is present in the installation directory I just need to update it. So not creating new component for updation

Comment: Could you please provide more details? An wxs file would be great. And did i understand you correctly that you have two scenarios:
1. Fill values of file by default values on install
2. On update update some values of xml file